# Firefox: navigator.getUserMedia is not a function

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-audio

I'm playing with browser and audio.

I'm doing this

```
        var session = {
          audio: true,
          video: false
        };
        var recordRTC = null;
        navigator.getUserMedia(session, initializeRecorder, onError);
```

But, using latest FF available I got a javascript error, saying that

> navigator.getUserMedia is not a function

I copied this code from this blog post: https://blog.groupbuddies.com/posts/39-tutorial-html-audio-capture-streaming-to-nodejs-no-browser-extensions

And similar on latest Chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

But I know that this api is supported from both browser

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you including `adapter.js`?

Comment: To account for all the unique prefixes for each of the individual browser implementations of `getUserMedia`. Or you can do it yourself as shown in any of the given answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Navigator.getUserMedia() is deprecated, advised to use MediaDevices.getUserMedia()

```
async function getMedia(pc) {
  let stream = null;

  try {
    stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
    /* use the stream */
  } catch(err) {
    /* handle the error */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 43):

It's not supported unprefixed yet. See http://caniuse.com/#search=getusermedia

You'll need to get the browser-specific prefix and use that. As posted in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28991911/3187556):

```
navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                       navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.msGetUserMedia);
```

This will set `navigator.getUserMedia` to whatever it detects to be the proper prefixed version.

Comment: I accetpted this because identical to the other, but it has been written one minute before.

Comment: Now we have to use `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` because `navigator.getUserMedia()` is deprecated and will display the same error message: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia

Answer (score 19):

Since `navigator.getUserMedia()` is deprecated, use this :

```
navigator.getUserMedia = (
    navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.msGetUserMedia
);

if (typeof navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia === 'undefined') {
    navigator.getUserMedia({
        audio: true
    }, streamHandler, errorHandler);
} else {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true
    }).then(streamHandler).catch(errorHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Check the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia), especially the first part of the first example:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                       navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.msGetUserMedia);
```

It's not that well-supported - you'll need browser prefixes.

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is

If the current document isn't loaded securely, navigator.mediaDevices will be undefined, and you cannot use getUserMedia(). See Security for more information on this and other security issues related to using getUserMedia()

as given in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

after searching, I got the solution
**try Following steps:**

1. Open Chrome browser, Type **chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure** in the url.
2. Add the path of your host/ local url (ex. localhost/myproject or YOUR_HOSTNAME)
3. Select as **Enabled**.
4. **Relaunch** Browser.

Answer (score -1):

I use `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` to find connected camera and have this error

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() is not a function
```

when any camera are not connected. I use React to develop front so to solve this create an .env file with `HTTPS=true'. Therefore in browser I can use https protocol to serve project and when the camera is not connected I have not any error.