# How to use webrtc in Angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular, webrtc

I tried to use webrtc in Angular 2 typescript and get the error: navigation.getUserMedia is not a function.

This is my code: [

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    navigator.getUserMedia(this.constraints,
      stream => {
        var track: MediaStreamTrack = stream.getTracks()[0];
        console.log('label:' + track.label);
        console.log('ended:' + track.readyState);
        track.onended = (event:Event) => console.log('Track ended');
        var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error message: ' + error.message);
        console.log('Error name: ' + error.name);
      });
  }
```

]
[Plunker Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/nAzPfpzXZLBWNZoVUv1h?p=preview)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think there is nothing related with Angular2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991835/firefox-navigator-getusermedia-is-not-a-function

Comment: I think this is your need. http://welrtc.firebaseapp.com WelRTC integrates with Webrtc, Angular 4 and Material Design.

Comment: Is there the sourcecode for welrtc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should include adapter.js: https://github.com/webrtc/adapter

Basically, you could just use the code from another answer:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                       navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.msGetUserMedia);
```

Although, there are even more WebRTC-functions that would remain inaccessible in that case. So, including adapter.js is more correct way. Moreover, it is maintained and updated by Google (one of the biggest WebRTC contributors).

Answer (score 7):

following is how I used webrtc in Angular 4 -->

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('hardwareVideo') hardwareVideo: any;

  _navigator = <any> navigator;
  localStream;

  ngOnInit() {

    const video = this.hardwareVideo.nativeElement;
    this._navigator = <any>navigator;

    this._navigator.getUserMedia = ( this._navigator.getUserMedia || this._navigator.webkitGetUserMedia
    || this._navigator.mozGetUserMedia || this._navigator.msGetUserMedia );

    this._navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
      .then((stream) => {
        this.localStream = stream;
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    });

  }

  stopStream() {
    const tracks = this.localStream.getTracks();
    tracks.forEach((track) => {
      track.stop();
    });
  }

}
```

template:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to my webRTC demo app!
  </h1>
  <button (click)="stopStream()">Stop Streaming</button>
  <video #hardwareVideo autoplay></video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

#### You have made a couple of mistakes:

1) `getUserMedia` delivers a Promise, there is lack of a `.then`

2) Use `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` instead of `navigator.getUserMedia`

3) The line `video = document.querySelector('video');` needs to be inside `ngOnInit`

4) As a consequence of 3) you need to declare `video: HTMLVideoElement;` in the first section.

5) Use `this.video.srcObject = stream` to put the stream on the HTMLVideoElement

#### When you put everything together you will get the following code:

```
import {Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Realtime communication with WebRTC</h1>
    <video autoplay></video>
  `
})
export class App {

  video: HTMLVideoElement;
  constraints = { audio: false, video: true };

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.video = document.querySelector('video');
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(this.constraints).then(
      stream => {
        this.video.srcObject = stream
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error: ' + error);
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before calling that function do this first:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                       navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.msGetUserMedia);
```