# JavaScript : error fetching webcam video using navigator.getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video

I am trying to fetch webcam video and show it in the browser, following is the html I use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DOCUMENT</title>

        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="booth">
        <video id="video" width="400" height="300" autoplay></video>
    </div>

    <script src="video.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the CSS:

```
.booth{
    width: 400px;
    background: #CCC;
    border: 10px solid #ddd;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

this is the javascript that I am using here:

```
    (function(){
    var video = document.getElementById('video'),vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

    navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                       navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.msGetUserMedia);
    //capture video

    navigator.getUserMedia({
        video:true,
        audio:false
    }, function(stream){
        video.src = vendorUrlcreateObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    }, function(error){
        //an error occured
        console.log(error)

    });

})();
```

in safari console I am facing an error that states:

> navigator.getUserMedia is not a function. (In 'navigator.getUserMedia', 'navigator.getUserMedia' is undefined)

and in chrome console,  I am getting this error:

> vendorUrlcreateObjectURL is not defined

please tell me where I went wrong!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991835/firefox-navigator-getusermedia-is-not-a-function

Comment: I tried that solution but didn't work for me, btw when I run this code in chrome I got another error: 'vendorUrlcreateObjectURL is not defined'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first error is a strange one, but I suspect Safari is preventing you from creating a new property on the `navigator` object.

It would be safer to simply create a local variable, rather than modifying built-in objects:

```
var getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                   navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                   navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                   navigator.msGetUserMedia;

if(!getUserMedia) {
  // Your error handling goes here
}

// ...
```

As for the second error, `vendorUrlcreateObjectURL` doesn't exist. Try `URL.createObjectURL()`!

Comment: well safari doesn't support that feature! and thanks for the answer, this works.. also if you have any way of accessing webcam in safari, please let me know!