# getUserMedia threw exception :TypeError: navigator.getUserMedia is not a function

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, getusermedia

I'm trying to build a guitar tuner using plain JavaScript. I need to access the user's microphone. To do this I used to be able to use Navigator.getUserMedia(), but this is now deprecated and not supported by any modern browsers. The code I would have previously used would look something like this

```
function getUserMedia(dictionary, callback) {
    try {
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia; navigator.getUserMedia(dictionary, callback, error);
    } catch (e) {
        alert('getUserMedia threw exception :' + e);
    }
}

function gotStream(stream) {
    // Create an AudioNode from the stream.
    mediaStreamSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

    // Connect it to the destination.
    analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
    analyser.fftSize = 2048;
    mediaStreamSource.connect( analyser );
    updatePitch();
}

function toggleLiveInput() {
    if (isPlaying) {
        //stop playing and return
        sourceNode.stop( 0 );
        sourceNode = null;
        analyser = null;
        isPlaying = false;
        if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
            window.cancelAnimationFrame = window.webkitCancelAnimationFrame;
        window.cancelAnimationFrame( rafID );
    }
    getUserMedia(
        {
            "audio": {
                "mandatory": {
                    "googEchoCancellation": "false",
                    "googAutoGainControl": "false",
                    "googNoiseSuppression": "false",
                    "googHighpassFilter": "false"
                },
                "optional": []
            },
        }, gotStream);
}
```

If I use this method it throws the error because it is not supported.

MDN advises using MediaDevices.getUserMedia() instead, but I can't figure out how to convert my existing code to use this.

I've found another question/answer that is similar here [Firefox: navigator.getUserMedia is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991835/firefox-navigator-getusermedia-is-not-a-function) so I changed the function to

```
async function getMedia(pc) {
  let stream = null;

  try {
    stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
    /* use the stream */
  } catch(err) {
    /* handle the error */
      alert('getUserMedia threw exception :' + err);
  }
}
```

and changed the call from getUserMedia to getMedia

Now it throws a new error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUserMedia' of undefined"

Could someone kindly show me how to use the new  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia method with my existing code? I think I'm just missing something obvious.

Comment: `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` only exists in a secure page (https) or when the host is `localhost` (maybe ... not sure about this one) see ["documentation"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)... is your page loaded securely? (https)

Comment: Jaromanda X is right, you need to deploy to a https server in order to test the microphone. I would recommend [LocalTunnel](https://localtunnel.github.io/www/) for testing on https.

Comment: @JaromandaX you're answer is correct. I tested it over https and the old version of my code running navigator.getUserMedia works. However, navigator.getUserMedia is deprecated and no longer works in IE or Safari. I need to convert my code to use navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia but I'm struggling to understand how to do this. I'm quite new to JS in general. I tried to just switch my function over (as above) but now nothing happens and I get no console errors. When I debugged it seems the function just isn't executing. I think it's because I have the incorrect arguments.

Comment: `no longer works in IE` - nothing has changed in IE for many years, so you've probably *done something wrong™*

Comment: Thanks, @JaromandaX. It was in fact caused by the "stream" variable name, which I'd already previously used. I swapped this around and used a new variable name and now the code seems to work in IE Edge so this issue is resolved.  HTTPS is the correct answer.